# Is it possible to pipe HDF5 formated data?

Tags: hdf5

It is possible to write HDF5 to stdout and read from stdin (via `H5::File file("/dev/stdout",H5F_ACC_RDONLY)` or otherwise)?

---

What I want is to have a program `foo` to write to an HDF5 file (taken to be its first argument, say) and another program `bar` to read from an HDF5 file and then instead of

```
command_prompt> foo temp.h5
command_prompt> bar temp.h5
command_prompt> rm temp.h5
```

simply say

```
command_prompt> foo - | bar -
```

where the programs `foo` and `bar` understand the special file name `-` to mean `stdout` and `stdin` respectively. In order to write those programs, I want to know 1) whether this is at all possible and 2) how I implement this, i.e. what to pass to `H5Fcreate()` and `H5Fopen()`, respectively, in case file name = `-`.

---

I tried and it seems impossible (not a big surprise). HDF5 only has `H5Fcreate()`, `H5Fopen()`, and `H5Freopen()`, neither of which seems to support I/O to `stdin/stdout`.

Comment: Of course that's possible.  HDF5 is just a data source, like any other.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark ?? so what? I think this has nothing to do with my question. I clarified that a bit for your benefit.

Comment: I salute your attempt to support streaming -- that can be very useful.  _If_ your HDF5 library supports streaming, it's likely that it will provide something like `H5Ffdopen()`, that lets you pass an already-open fd or FILE *.  On the other hand, if they only give you `H5Fopen`, it's likely they don't support it, and it's likely that using a special filename like `/dev/stdin` won't work.  If they don't support it, it's likely because, as another answer notes, they expect to be able to seek around while reading or writing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Unfortunately, that's wrong. HDF5 is a data source but not a stream.

Comment: @Walter: Any data source can be converted into a stream, given sufficient programming effort.  It may lack some features, and you may have to confine your input to a particular *part* of the data, but it's certainly possible to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can use `stdin` as an hdf5 input file. The library needs to seek around between the header contents and the data, and you cannot do that with `stdin`.

Comment: No, I am not an HDF5 expert. But I would be very surprised if reading from stdin were possible.